# trigger willReceiveProps during initial render cycle

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, lifecycle

If an async action is called on the `componentWillMount` phase of the lifecycle, is there a way to get `willReceiveProps` to fire once that action is complete?

Example

```
class asyncComponent extends react.component() {
    static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object, 
        dispatch: propTypes.func
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchAsnycData()) //Updates data prop once async fetch is done
    }

    render() {
        <DumbComponent data={this.props.data} />
    }

}

class DumbComponent extends react.Component() {
    static propTypes = { data: PropTypes.object }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        console.log(this.props.data) //never called
    }

    render() {...}

}
```

Here the `componentWillReceiveProps()` method is never called, because even though the component did receive props, because the action was fired in the `componentWillMount` lifecycle phase, it is considered part of the first rendering.

Comment: You have a typo in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: double checked my code, it's spelled correctly there. Fixed the typo here.

Comment: I'll fix that too. I wrote this sample here by hand, it's all correct in my actual code.

Comment: Well, if you async action finishes before `componentDidMount` then `componentWillReceiveProps` won't be called. That's why you should start actions in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: thank you @Sulthan for the useful info. I think what I posted in the answer is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from @suthan in the comments, I came up with this working solution:

```
class asyncComponent extends react.component() {
    static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object, 
        dispatch: propTypes.func
    }

    childDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchAsnycData()) //Updates data prop once async fetch is done
    }

    render() {
        <DumbComponent data={this.props.data} 
            componentDidMount={this.childDidMount}.bind(this) />
    }

}

class DumbComponent extends react.Component() {
    static propTypes = { data: PropTypes.object, componentDidMount: PropTypes.func }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        console.log(this.props.data) //works!
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.componentDidMount();
    }

    render() {...}

}
```

I had tried already, putting the action in the `componentDidMount` method of the parent component. The trick was realizing that the parent component mounts before the child, so the action needed to be fired on the `componentDidMount` stage of the child. Passing a reference to the function from the parent allowed me to keep my stateless component and achieve the desired results.